# Add the "App Groups" entitlement to your entitlements file?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode6.3

I'm adding a watchkit extension to an iPhone app and have set up everything correctly, I think. However, I continually get the error in Xcode that I need to "Add the 'App Groups' entitlement to your entitlements file.". (see attached)
[image]

I click the "Fix Issue" button and the complaint goes away. Until I rebuild and the complaint returns.

I do have an entitlements file and it appears to have the correct entry for: com.apple.security.application-groups

I've double-checked our entitlements settings for the app in the developer portal and they seem correct.

Interestingly...if I delete the file and do "Fix Issue" Xcode will recreate the file but not create an entry for the app group.

I've been struggling with this for weeks and have run out of things to try to remedy. Would love some assistance.

Comment: Have you tried a beta build of Xcode? Same result?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly same problem. I resolved it but can't remember exact steps but did something like this:

I disabled 'App Groups' in capabilities, recreated provisioning profiles in Member Center, restarted Xcode and reloaded provisioning profiles (Xcode > Preferences...). Then re-enabled 'App Groups'. In some phase I also cleaned the project (before exiting Xcode I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem. Clean Build - Command+Option+Shift+k resolved the problem for me.